# RxJava lifetime Observable

Tags: java, android, rx-java, observable

Interactor lives all time existence app. 
And some method from there:

```
 //Interactor
public Observable<Pair<Boolean, String>> getGiftPayPalObservable(Params params)
{
    return session.getTokenObservable().flatMap(token ->
    {
        [1]
        if (params.getType() == GiftCard)
        {
            return apiStorage.getGiftResult(token, params.getEmail());
        }
        else
        {
            return apiStorage.getPayPalResult(token, params.getEmail());
        }
    })
            .doOnError(Observable::error)
            .subscribeOn(getThreadExecutor().getBackgroundThread());
}

private final Session session;
```

And my menthod to call

```
tokenObservable.onNext(Prefs.getString(TOKEN_KEY, NO_TOKE)); [2]
```

I call method **getGiftPayPalObservable** from **ViewModel**. And all is normal. But then i destroy fragment. And after that i run code **[2]** to logout and i'm getting to place in my code **[1]** but my ViewModel has not already exist at this moment. That's why i get crash app.

How can i don't get to place **[1]** can i usubscribe?

I can't avoid to use **session.getTokenObservable()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem like this:

```
  return session.getTokenObservable()
            .filter(token -> !token.equals(session.getNoToke()))
            .flatMap(token ->
```

With help filter i just don't get into **[1]** when token is empty.